# apache htaccess multiple http method condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm desperately trying to build a REST like API. Therefore, I created a .htaccess file, which should redirect the request to the right file, depending on the request method.

I managed to get this working for GET and POST requests, but something is wrong when I try to add a third request method like PUT or DELETE.

This is my htaccess (shorted):

```
#######################
# GET DATA URIs
#######################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET

##### EMPLOYEE
# Load all employees
RewriteRule ^rest/employee$ /moduls/employee/rest/get/get_all.php 
# get all data form a specific employee
RewriteRule ^rest/employee/([0-9]*)$ /moduls/employee/rest/get/get.php?id=$1
# And the employee sub resources
# BASE DATA
RewriteRule ^rest/employee/([0-9]*)/base_data$ /moduls/employee/rest/get/base_data.php?id=$1
# CONTRACT DATA
RewriteRule ^rest/employee/([0-9]*)/contract$ /moduls/employee/rest/get/contract.php?id=$
#######################
# CREATE DATA URIs
#######################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
# REST URLs for employee
# Add new employee
RewriteRule ^rest/employee$ /moduls/employee/rest/add.php

#######################
# EDIT DATA URIs
#######################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =PUT
##### EMPLOYEE
RewriteRule ^rest/employee/([0-9]*)/base_data$ /moduls/employee/rest/edit/base_data.php?id=$1
```

When I start a request to `rest/employee` it depends on the method which script is executed. This works fine, but when I try to load `/rest/employee/XXX/base_data` using a PUT request apache always redirects me to the script that should be executed when a GET Request was permitted.

I'm quite new to .htaccess and can't see where the error is :-/

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you decided to handle routing logic in Apache rather than at the application layer. You could just as easily have a single `FallbackResource` declaration pointing all requests to a front controller and have that front controller inspect the incoming request to perform routing. This would be more flexible as you add more endpoints to your RESTful service.

Comment: well, first thanks for your interest. Its a bit difficult. The programm sperates really, really strict between every script. Each file has exactly one purpose. They share a lot of code (just neccesary due to the size), also part of the module designe, but thats not the point anyway ;) any idea what could be twrong above?